# When to increase or decrease ring parameters for NIC's?

Tags: networking

Under what conditions is it appropriate to:

1. Increase ring parameters
2. Decrease ring parameters

[Improving TCP performance over a gigabit network with lots of connections and high traffic of small packets](https://serverfault.com/questions/357799/improving-tcp-performance-over-a-gigabit-network-with-lots-of-connections-and-hi) suggests that increasing rx/tx buffers may help when

> you are getting too many interrupts on your network card. If Bandwidth is not the problem, frequency is the problem

Comment: Speaking for myself: I'm very lazy and I assume that by default settings have reasonable general purpose values. I try to avoid tuning unless benchmarking and load testing point to problems.

Comment: @HBruijn I operate the same way with defaults. I'm more or less trying to get an understanding of the problems that should raise alarm when the defaults need adjusted.