# iptables causing connection to stall

Tags: centos, iptables

We are having connection stall issues on many of our http servers. As a test I have created a script that connects to the webserver using curl and tries do download a txt file of about 3mb size.

Every now and then the speed goes down to 0 and the connection hangs.

When I disable iptables the problem resolves and everything works ok.

```
 iptables -vL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   28  2080 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
   17  1924 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15 packets, 1564 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

There is couple of routers and firewalls in between.

Any ideas what this could cause?

Ah. I use Centos 6.3 Kernel  2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64
Iptables version is: iptables-1.4.7-5.1.el6_2.x86_64

Drop message

```
IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:a6:00:9e:00:16:9c:ff:20:00:08:00 SRC=xxx DST=xxx LEN=80 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=55755 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34787 DPT=80 WINDOW=1539 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Comment: Anything in the nat table `iptables -vL -t nat`? Also, how do you disable iptables?

Comment: Nothing in the nat table as I don't do any nat. I disable iptables by shuting down the service . (service iptables stop)

Comment: Are these the iptables settings on the web server machine?

Comment: yes. it somehow fixed the issue by setting tcp_sack to 0 on the webserver. Not sure if this is whise or not or what the reason is that it works like that

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are running out of [connection tracking entries](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Increase_simultaneous/concurrent_TCP_connections_%28Linux%29). Raise `net.nf_conntrack_max`. If this is due to an attack, you may need to raise it quite a bit and decrease some settings like `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv`.

You could just rewrite your rules without connection tracking -- you don't seem to need it. That might reduce your flexibility in the future though.

Comment: Hi. I was able to fix it by disabling tcp_sack. not sure what this does or if this is a whise idea. maybe this hint tells you more than me :)

Comment: @Chris: Are you sure that's the only change you made? That would suggest you have some kind of ancient firewall in the path or are under a [sack attack](http://serverfault.com/a/11002/91987).

Comment: yes. I can watch it live how the connection drops as soon as I enable this again... I am not aware on the firewalls in between but I have a meeting tomorrow with one of the network guys. anything I could ask them? By the way. This happens to all our webservers that are in that specific network zone

Comment: Ask them if there's anything unusual about the way that zone is connected to other networks. Report your findings and see if they believe you. ;)